# Solutions behavior of i.v.p $y'(x)+e^x(2+\sin x)y(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1},\ y(0)=a,\ x\geq 0 $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem (i.v.p) $$y'(x)+e^x(2+\sin x)y(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1},\ y(0)=a,\ x\geq 0\ \ (a\in\mathbb{R}). $$
The unique solution of this problem has the form
$$y(x)=e^{-\int_0^x e^s(2+\sin s)ds}\left(a+\int_0^x \frac {1}{1+t^2}e^{\int_0^t e^s(2+\sin s)ds}dt\right),\ x\geq 0 $$
Firstly, I proved that for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty} y(x)=0$ (note that $e^x(2+\sin x)\geq 1,\forall\ x\geq 0$ and $\frac{1}{x^2+1}\to 0$, as $x\to +\infty$). However, I have a problem with those two questions:

$\bullet$ Can I tell with certainty, that there exist a solution $y$ of the i.v.p such that $y(x)<0,\forall x\geq x_0$ (for some $x_0\geq 0$)?

$\bullet$ Can I tell with certainty, that there exist an oscillative solution $y$ (i.e solution that has infinite countable roots) of the i.v.p?

Is it possible the answer lies hidden at the asymptotic behavior of those integrals?

Hint: Calculation of integrals isn't necessary.

Thanks for your help!! I appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varphi(t) := \int_0^t \exp(s)(2 + \sin s)\mathrm{d}s.$ Then we know that $$ y(x;a) = \exp(-\varphi(x)) \left( a + \int_0^x \frac{\exp(\varphi(t))}{1+t^2}\mathrm{d}t\right).$$ But note that $\exp( -\varphi(x)) > 0,$ and so the sign of your solution is the same as the sign of $$z(x;a) :=  a + \int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^2} \exp(\varphi(t)) \mathrm{d}t.$$

Now, by differentiating via Leibniz's rule (and so using the smoothness of $\varphi$), we see that $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} z(x;a) = \frac{\exp(\varphi(x))}{1+x^2} > 0,$$ and so $z$ is monotone. This means that $z$ can have at most one root, and thus $y$ can have at most one root. This means that your second question has the answer no.

Also note that $$ \exp(\varphi(t)) \ge 1 + \varphi(t) = 1+ \int_0^t e^s(2+\sin s) \mathrm{d}s \ge 1 + \int_0^t e^s\mathrm{d}s =  e^t. $$

Thus, we find that $$ z(x;a) \ge a + \int_0^x \frac{e^t}{1 + t^2}\mathrm{d}t \ge a + \frac{e^x -1}{1+x^2}.$$ But then $\lim_{x \to \infty} z(x;a) = +\infty,$ which means that the sign of $y(x)$ must be positive for large $x$. So your first question also has the answer no.

Comment: Thanks a lot your solution is very understandable